# cmake not finding package configuration file

Tags: cmake, find-package

I am using Qt Creator as IDE and MSVC 2019.
I built and installed the pagmo library from the source. Now I am trying to use it for my project.

Even though the installation seems fine, when I try to load it I get strange errors, telling me that "pagmo" is not found. In particular:

```
error:
 By not providing "FindPagmo.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Pagmo",
 but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Pagmo" with any
  of the following names:

    PagmoConfig.cmake
    pagmo-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Pagmo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set 
  "Pagmo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
  "Pagmo" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

In my CMakeLists.txt I have set the following command:

- `find_package(Pagmo REQUIRED)`

Now, as far as I know FindPagmo.cmake does not exist, BUT I am giving as input parameter `Pagmo_DIR`, which contains the file pagmo-config.cmake. I can't understand why CMake is not finding it. I also tried to set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the same folder but nothing changed.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to solve this problem?

I am setting pagmo directory as follows:

`-DPagmo_DIR = C:\Lib\pagmo\install\debug\lib\cmake\pagmo`

in that folder I have the following files:

- Findpagmo_IPOPT.cmake;
- pagmo_export.cmake;
- pagmo_export-debug.cmake;
- pagmo-config.cmake;
- pagmo-config-version.cmake;
- PagmoFindBoost.cmake

Comment: Show the relevant parts: `find_package`, how you set `Pagmo_DIR` what is the content of the folder you set `Pagmo_DIR` to. `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is useless if you don't have FindPagmo.cmake.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the question with further details.

Comment: Try `-DPagmo_DIR=C:/Lib/pagmo/install/debug/lib/cmake/pagmo`

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed

Comment: @ixSci: Please, do not format error messages using *blockquote*. This formatting doesn't preserve **newlines**, making the text harder to read and interpret. Instead, use **code** formatting.

Comment: @Tsyvarev in this case it is impossible to read with the code formatting.

Comment: Add `message("Pagmo dir: '${Pagmo_DIR}'")` right before `find_package(Pagmo REQUIRED)` and show us the output.

Comment: @ixSci: Yes, the post initially contains the error message where newlines (and indentations) has already been missed. I have fixed it according to usual output of CMake in such cases.

Comment: @ixSci Adding this message returns the following output:

`Pagmo dir: '' `

Comment: Now you have your answer, you do not set the variable. Find out why you don't do it and fix it.

Comment: Thank you,@ixSci
I succeeded in loading pagmo in the end. I was setting CMake commands with the `batch edit` option and somehow it would not work. Using instead `additional cmake options` it worked.